# "32-bit libraries not found on this system" when trying to install the Intel C++ Composer

Tags: intel, c++

I am installing Intel C++ Composer (Non-commercial version) for Linux with x32 and x64 target. During installation i get the warning message:

```
Step no: 4 of 6 | Options > Missing Optional Pre-requisite
```

---

```
32-bit libraries not found on this system.
This product release requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries
when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems. One or more of these libraries
could not be found:
  libstdc++ (including libstdc++6)
  glibc
   libgcc
Without these libraries, the compiler will not function properly.  Please refer 
to Release Notes for more information.
```

I have installed

```
ia32-libs
```

but it didn't solve the issue. I have installed

```
libstdc++
```

and regardless to it, it cannot be found anyways.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are glibc and libgcc installed?

Comment: no, and the problem is that sudo apt-get install reports that these are unknown packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you can try is ignoring this message and continuing to install anyway, which is actually the default option. I did this and it seemed to work, although I haven't thoroughly tested it.

Another possibility is downloading the version that is intended for intel64. I believe you are getting this message because what you are trying to install includes both 32-bit and 64-bit functionality, but you really only need 64-bit. Go back to the same download page, but click this package instead:

`l_ccompxe_intel64_2013.1.117.tgz`

[Direct link (requires login)](http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/2850/l_ccompxe_intel64_2013.1.117.tgz)

I tried this too, and it installed without any warnings or errors.

Comment: 404 for the moment.

Answer (score -1):

install g++-multilib

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```